# Android Logcat: W/ApplicationPackageManager(22470): getCSCPackageItemText()

Tags: android, logcat, galaxy

I'm working on a big Android project and recently the logcat shows so many  `W/ApplicationPackageManager(22470): getCSCPackageItemText()` log.

This seems only occurring on Galaxy S4.

Anyone would kindly tell me the cause of such log? such as invoking some specific API.

```
01-26 12:03:13.820: W/ApplicationPackageManager(22470): getCSCPackageItemText()
01-26 12:03:13.820: W/ApplicationPackageManager(22470): getCSCPackageItemText()
01-26 12:03:13.820: W/ApplicationPackageManager(22470): getCSCPackageItemText()
01-26 12:03:13.825: W/ApplicationPackageManager(22470): getCSCPackageItemText()
01-26 12:03:13.825: W/ApplicationPackageManager(22470): getCSCPackageItemText()
01-26 12:03:13.825: W/ApplicationPackageManager(22470): getCSCPackageItemText()
```

Comment: You'll have to ask Samsung. Even if you knew what was causing it, there's probably nothing you could do about it. FWIW, Samsung devices tend to be very "noisy" in Logcat.